Pytube throws http error 403 Forbidden since a few days
I am on Python 3.12 and use Pytube 15.0.0 and have written a small charts downloader.
Until a few days ago everything worked fine, but now YouTube must have changed something and I get the http error message “403 Forbidden” when I try to download. I download the audio_only stream with Pytube. I have tried the solutions mentioned in previous posts, but neither changing the user agent in the innertube.py file to WEB or ANDROID nor completely uninstalling and reinstalling Pytube worked or improved the situation.
Does anyone here have a solution to the problem? Are there any other modules for Python to download clips from Youtube?
Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Likely question and answer referenced by the author:  pytube urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

As I wrote in my question, I have already tried these solutions. Unfortunately, they were not successful.

I used  pytubefix as I had same error and nothing fixed it.

I had the same issue with pytube giving an HTTP 403 error. I switched to yt-dlp, but then got this error:

ERROR: [youtube] XCZWyN9ZbEQ: Sign in to confirm you’re not a bot. Use --cookies-from-browser or --cookies for the authentication. 

1 -
Use the 'Get Cookies.txt' extension in Chrome to export cookies to a cookies.txt file from a logged-in session.
Then simply pass it into ydl options like below:

ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': f"{output_path}/%(title)s.%(ext)s", 'cookiefile': 'cookies.txt'}

2 -
Else you can use this option to load cookies directly from browser:

ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': f"{output_path}/%(title)s.%(ext)s", 'cookiesfrombrowser': ('chrome',)}

Both worked fine for me.
Hope it can help you.
Enjoy :)

Just tested this for a playlist, using firefox instead of chrome. Works perfectly

Thank you very much, works like a charm. And it's very fast too.

option 1 worked for me

i fixed this problem using pytubefix package instead pytube.
install with pip install pytubefix
from pytubefix import YouTube # This is solution



ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from pytubefix import Youtube # This is solution
3 def download_video(video_url, output_path="."):
4     try:
5         # Create YouTube object
ImportError: cannot import name 'Youtube' from 'pytubefix' (c:\Users\dell\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytubefix_init_.py)

Avoid saying what you did, and write your answer more like this: "The error is caused... Using pytubefix instead of pytube may resolve the issue", You can install it using pip install pytubefix ...

I had the same issue, I fixed it by using yt_dlp
First install the package

pip install yt_dlp

Import and use it

from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
URLS = [link]
with YoutubeDL() as ydl:
        ydl.download(URLS)

